# Make file is failing to create object files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Basically I am trying to make a simple make file that creates a lexer.o and then a driver.o file combining them into an executable.

Code below shows what has been tried. Running it in Windows powershell using GNU make.

```
.PRECIOUS = driver.cpp lexer.h lexer.cpp

lexer.o: lexer.cpp lexer.h
    g++ -o $@ -c lexer.cpp

driver.o: driver.cpp lexer.h
    g++ -o $@ -c driver.cpp

lex.exe: lexer.o driver.o
    g++ -o $@ $^

clean: 
    $(RM) *.o lex.exe
```

Here is what output is given. I was expecting it to create the lexer.o file, but instead it cannot "find" the file it was supposed to create.

```
g++ -o lexer.o -c lexer.cpp
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, g++ -o lexer.o -c lexer.cpp, ...) 
failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [lexer.o] Error 2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This looks like a powershell problem, not a Make problem.

Comment: This is complaining that the compiler (g++) is not found.  Do you have the GCC compiler installed on your system?  If so do you have it on your PATH?

Comment: @MadScientist You were correct, I also swapped back over to Linux. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up just being a G++ installation problem. I swapped over to Ubuntu and reinstalled everything and it worked fine.